# Find application using port

Tags: c#, wmi, netstat

I have a networking program setup that does a lot of what the nestat program does.  I am working now on netstat -o.  That command will give me the PID of the program using that socket.
I have some idea of where to look.  I have been trying to use WMI to get that information but so far I have not found a suitable class.

How can I find the PID or application name that is using a particular socket?

I am using c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, this information is not exposed anywhere in the BCL or WMI. You'll need to p/Invoke [GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928(v=VS.85).aspx) to get it.

Comment: How do you use it from c#?

Comment: As I stated in the answer, you'll need to P/Invoke `GetExtendedTcpTable`.

Comment: FWIW, I wrote a batch script to parse netstat output: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26839729/1569434

Answer (score 2):

Go here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/iphlpapi2.aspx  I have used it and it works really well.