# Which application is using a given HTTP port?

Tags: c#, exception, port, conflict

I've got a conflict in the usage of the port 80 and I want to give the best error message I can.

So I'd like to check by the exception handling which is the other program listening to the same port, and with whom I'm in conflict.

How can I do?

The exception details:

> System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException was unhandled
>   Message="HTTP could not register URL .... because TCP port 80 is being
>   used by another application"

Comment: Seems like you're looking for this: [Find application using port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173427/find-application-using-port)

Answer (score 1):

You need some app for this, like TCP Viewer. You can find it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Read the link below and use a small command in command prompt. read the paragraph below:

"The Netstat.exe utility has a new switch, the -o switch, that can display the process identifier (ID) that is associated with each connection. This information can be used to determine which process (program) listens on a given port. For example, the netstat -ano command can produce the following output."

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281336

Comment: It's good.. but how do I use it from c#?

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK you cannot infer the program using a port from the exception mentioned above.
A similar question seems to have already been asked and answered:

[Find application using port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173427/find-application-using-port)

Maybe the codeproject article referenced from there (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/iphlpapi2.aspx) can get you the data you need.

Comment: No, you can infer.. try netstat.. the problem is finding it out from c#

Comment: Of course I was referring to C#. It was a C# question. Why the downvote?

Comment: Because this is not an answer, you said it yourself "have already been asked and answered". That's why we have the close vote as duplicate which also automatically add a comment with the link.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, yesterday, the only option I had was posting an answer because of my then too low reputation. This is why I "answered" instead of "commented".